# Bash: copying files with find, naming them with progressive numbers

Tags: bash, gnu-findutils

I am trying to write a script to copy all files in a directory tree to another directory, using find command. However, some files have the same name as other. Since I am not interested in file names at all, I thought that the simplest solution would be to give to the copies progressive numbers as names. 
I tried with this command:

```
i=0

find . -iname "*.jpg" -exec  cp {} $DEST_DIR/$i ; i=$i+1;
```

however, this command obviously won't work, as -exec runs a subshell in which i variable is not defined.
Has anyone got some idea to do this, preferably with find? Is there any other better way to do it?

Comment: Just use `--backup` to `cp` and let it rename the files for you?

Comment: my version of cp (on Mac OS X) does not provide this option

Answer (score 1):

```
i=0; find . -iname "*.jpg" | while IFS= read -r f; do echo "$f" "$i"; i=$((i + 1)); done
```

... assuming there are no files with spaces in their name and such

Comment: This should work for any newline-free file names, and that case can be handled with careful use of `-print0` and adjusting the `read` command. (I think `IFS= read -d '' -r f` is sufficient.)

Comment: The leading `i=0` is not all that useful if the increment happens before use (files start at 1). It won't get changed by the loop.